# documentclass Beamer graphicspath subfolder

Tags: beamer, graphics

I want to use a subfolder for my graphics.
Folder structure:
script,
graphic,
Chapter1

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\graphicspath{{graphic/Chapter1}}
```

Latex wont find the images in the folder Chapter1

It works without subfolder

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\graphicspath{{graphic/}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a trailing `/` at the end of the first version, try:

```
\graphicspath{{graphic/Chapter1/}}
```